# Свой модуль для Joomla

Tags: joomla

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, есть ли толковое руководство по созданию собственного модуля для joomla 1.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видео-пособие: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwu71UX329I